# Raising Events from a thread safely

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading

I am having some problems with events being raised from the non-UI thread, in that i dont wish to have to handle the If me.invokerequired on every event handler added to the thread in Form1.

I am sure i have read somewhere how to use a delegate event (on SO) but i am unable to find it.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private WithEvents _to As New ThreadedOperation

    Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button.Click
        _to.start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub _to_SomthingHappend(ByVal result As Integer) Handles _to.SomthingHappend
        TextBox.Text = result.ToString //cross thread exception here
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class ThreadedOperation

    Public Event SomthingHappend(ByVal result As Integer)
    Private _thread As Threading.Thread

    Public Sub start()
        If _thread Is Nothing Then
            _thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Work)
        End If
        _thread.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Work()
        For i As Integer = 0 To 10
            RaiseEvent SomthingHappend(i)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You derived your class from Control.  A bit unusual, but if the control is actually hosted on a form, you can use Me.Invoke() to marshal the call.  For example:

```
  Private Delegate Sub SomethingHappenedDelegate(ByVal result As Integer)

  Private Sub Work()
    For i As Integer = 0 To 10
      Me.Invoke(New SomethingHappenedDelegate(AddressOf SomethingHappenedThreadSafe), i)
      Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
    Next
  End Sub

  Private Sub SomethingHappenedThreadSafe(ByVal result As Integer)
    RaiseEvent SomthingHappend(result)
  End Sub
```

If this class object is not actually hosted on a form, you'll need to pass a reference to the form so it can call Invoke():

```
  Private mHost As Form

  Public Sub New(ByVal host As Form)
    mHost = host
  End Sub
```

and use mHost.Invoke().  Or BeginInvoke().

The last trick in the book is to use your main startup form as the synchronization object.  That's not completely safe but works in 99% of the case:

```
  Dim main As Form = Application.OpenForms(0)
  main.Invoke(New SomethingHappenedDelegate(AddressOf SomethingHappenedThreadSafe), i)
```

Beware that there's a bug in WF that prevents OpenForms() from accurately tracking open forms when they get dynamically recreated.

Comment: I have gone with the second suggestion, passing the host control (I pass in a control object rather than a form though).  thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simplify all of this there is a class available called BackgroundWorker that handles the GUI thread marshaling for you.

Comment: Yeah, i know about/use the Background Worker a lot, this component however needs to have greater control over its thread(s)