# Updating GUI items upon an event raised by a thread of another class VB.nET

Tags: vb.net, event-handling, multithreading

**How to update data in GUI with messages that are being received by a thread of another class ?**

I have a class with a thread that receives data from a server. This thread raises an event whenever it gets a message from the server. This event is handled inside the Starter Class (main class which contains the GUI).
The event handler (say `DisplayData()`  has to display the message received by the other class.
My code is like this

```
Class GUI
    receiverObj = New Receiver()
    Addhandler receiverObj.MessageAlert, Addressof DisplayData
    ...
    ...
    Sub DisplayData()
        Dim str As receiverObj.ReceiveData

        lbEvents.Add.Items(str)   ' lbEvents is a ListBox inside the GUI that displays messages from Receiver 
    End Sub
End Class


Class Receiver

    Public Event MessageAlert()
    Sub New ()
        MyTcpClient = New TcpClient(hostIP, port)               
        MyTcpClient.GetStream.BeginRead(ReceiveData, 0, PacketSize, AddressOf ReceiveStream, Nothing)
    End Sub

    Public Sub ReceiveStream(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
        Dim ByteCount As Integer

        Try
            ByteCount = MyTcpClient.GetStream.EndRead(ar)
            Dim t As New Threading.Thread(Sub() RaiseEvent MessageAlert())
            MyTcpClient.GetStream.BeginRead(ReceiveData, 0, PacketSize, AddressOf ReceiveStream, Nothing)
     End Sub
End Class
```

The Window crashes or hangs and the listbox does not display data. Throws exception saying

**Cross-thread operation not valid: Control xxx accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.**

Can anybody suggest a way to fix this error ?
How to update data in GUI with messages that are being received by a thread of another class ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Raising Events from a thread safely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292715/raising-events-from-a-thread-safely)

Answer (score 5):

Updates to GUI elements of a Windows application must take place on the thread that created the GUI.

To fix this, there's a method called Invoke that allows you to fire a *delegate* that can ensure control is passed to the GUI thread and perform the update you are attempting.

You need a few things to make this work:

1. A *Delegate* type , such as

   ```
   Delegate Sub MyGUIUpdateDelegate()
   ```
2. A variable of the type of your delegate

   ```
   Public myGUIUpdateDelegate as MyGUIUpdateDelegate
   ```
3. A method having a signature that matches the delegate and does the work:

   ```
   Public Sub MyGuiEventHandler()

           ' Do work on proper GUI thread, via Control.Invoke,
           ' such as listbox population

           If (Me.InvokeRequired) Then
               Me.Invoke( myGUIUpdateDelegate)
           Else
               // do control specific work, we're on the GUI thread here
           End If
   ```

   End Sub
4. An assignment of the event handler to your delegate:

   `myGUIUpdateDelegate = New MyGuiUpdateDelegate(AddressOf myForm.MyGuiEventHandler)`
5. A call to your updater method via Control.Invoke to the proper thread from the event thread (assuming
   your form instance variable is named myForm):

   `myForm.Invoke(myForm.myGUIUpdateDelegate);`

That's at least a framework that should help you get started. The idea is that the background thread that wants to induce the update should not (and in reality, cannot) make direct GUI updates. The proper way to initiate a context switch to the GUI thread is by calling the Invoke method to call the GUI updater on the proper GUI thread.

Additionally, if you need to pass parameters to your delegate, simply alter the signature of the Delegate you define to include the parameter(s), and modify the Invoke method to provide the arguments in the handler, and the 2nd argument to Invoke.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is kind of lame that .Net forces you to do all that overcoding.